# How do I upgrade to MVC 3 from MVC 2 and leave my code unchanged?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

We are planning on upgrading our VS 2010 solution from MVC2 to MVC4 (without changing code because it's backwards-compatible).

I understand that we have to upgrade to MVC3 first. How can I upgrade our solution to MVC3 without changing our codebase?

The reason is that we want to start using MVC4 for new code and at the same time, we want the current code unmodified.

If anyone can help, I greatly appreciate it. All of the solutions that I've seen have some sort of tool to convert it automatically, but I'm scared that our current code-base would be modified and potentially break.

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "without changing code"? In MVC 4 some functions are deprecated/removed or changed, so I think you will have to upgrade your code base as well. If you have your code in source control you can always rollback to the working MVC 2 version.

Comment: You are correct. I've used this as a guide: http://mvcdecoder.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/upgrade-application-from-asp-net-mvc2-to-mvc3/

Comment: By the way, are you still using the ASPX viewengine? Consider changing to Razor. It is worth the effort.

Comment: Yes, I actually am using the ASPX view engine throughout my entire solution. We have plans to use Razor in the future and refactor our code. Since it's so huge, this will take some effort. An immediate benefit is that every new page we want to implement will be using Razor 2.0 (hopefully after I upgrade to MVC 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution here is an extremely customized MVC2 solution. Our solution is the most customized MVC2 solution that I have encountered. Still, this link guides you through it and it works!

This worked for me:

**ASP.NET MVC2 to MVC3**

http://mvcdecoder.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/upgrade-application-from-asp-net-mvc2-to-mvc3/

**ASP.NET MVC3 to MVC4 (directly from the ASP.NET whitepaper)**
Do this manually:

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806